# Homomorphism $f: \mathbb{C}^{*}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$. Prove that kernel of f is infinite group.

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

First of all we need to prove that $\ker(f)$ is group by proving:

1. That $\ker(f)$ contains $e\in\mathbb{C}^*$,
2. That $\ker(f)$ is closed under multiplication for every $a,b \in \ker(f)$
3. That $\ker(f)$ contains $a^{-1}$ for every $a\in\ker(f)$.

These statements are quite easy to prove, using : $f(a*b)=f(a)+f(b)$

The main problem for me is to prove to statements:

1. $\ker(f)\neq\{e\}$.
2. $\ker(f)$ is infinite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hints:*

1) Where does $-1$ go to?

2) $\mathbb{C}^*$ contains elements of finite order. What are the elements of finite order in $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of *any* group homomorphism is a subgroup, so there's nothing to prove there (unless you haven't seen that theorem yet!)

For the second part, consider $f(i)^2=f(i^2) = f(-1) = f((-i)^2) = f(-i)^2$. What does that tell you about $f(i)$ and $f(-i)$?